# C looping counting up

Tags: c, loops, counting

I'm a beginner at C and can't find the answer to this anywhere because I don't know how to word it so I'm just going to ask a question.
I understand basic looping but what I want to do is make a small program where the output is this using only loops:

- 12345
- 1234
- 123
- 12
- 1

my code so far

```
int x;
int y = 1;

for (x=1; x<=5; x++)
{
        while(y<=5)
        {
            printf("%d", y);
            y++;
        }
}
```

this is what I have so far and don't know where to go next, if anyone could help I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close.  Your outer loop needs to count down, not up, and your inner loop needs to count from 1 to x.

```
int x, y;

for (x=5; x>=1; x--)
{
    for (y=1;y<=x;y++)
    {
        printf("%d", y);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another solution using just a **FOR** loop with **Integer Division**. Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int n= 12345, i;

    for(i=n;i>0;i/=10){
        printf("%d\n",i);
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to see the pattern you want and apply it in the loops to get it.

You need the output `12345 1234 123 12 1`. So, the first iteration should start at `1` and go till `5`, second should start at `1` and go till `4`, and so on..

So, the outer loop should give the end limits for the inner loop, and the inner one should always start with `1`.

Try

```
for (x=5; x>=1; x--)
{
    y = 1;              // because the number always start with 1
    while(y<=x)
    {
        printf("%d", y);
        y++;
    }
    printf("\n");       //to go to next line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun: another approach that simply divides each loop.  But use [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508622/2410359)

```
int main(void) {
  int x = 12345;
  do {
    printf("%d\n", x);
    x /= 10;
  } while (x);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `integer division` and use one single loop:

```
int x = 12345;

// repeat this loop as long as x != 0
while (x)
{
    printf("%d\n", x);
    x /= 10; // x = x/10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 2 changes to your outer loop in order to get the expected output.

1. `for (x=1; x<=5; x++)` should be `for (x=1; x<=5; x--)` because your program will count up to 5 the first time, 4 the second time, 3 the third time, etc..
2. You should include `printf("\n")` so a new line is printed after each sequence is output.

You need to make 1 change to your inner loop as well:

1. Instead of `y <= 5` you should say `y <= x` because `x` will always be equal to the last number that you want to print since you're decrementing it in the outer loop.